# MongoDB - MongoEngine - Saving an embedded document doesn't work - Has no attribute save

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, database

I have an embedded document class `Post` and a father-class `Thread`.

```
class Thread(Document):
    ...
    posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("Post"))

class Post(EmbeddedDocument): 
    attribute = StringField()
    ...
```

I want to create a new post and add it to my `ListField` in the `Thread` class.

My code looks like this:

```
post = Post()
post.attribute = "noodle"
post.save()
thread.posts.append(post)
thread.save()
```

But I get the following error message:

> "'Post' object has no attribute 'save'"

If I skip the `post.save()` an empty `Post` object is appended to my `Thread`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not about programming embedded systems. Retagged.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks fine - are you sure you don't have other thread objects?  Heres a test case proving your code (without the post.save() step).  What version do you have installed?

```
import unittest
from mongoengine import *


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        conn = connect(db='mongoenginetest')

    def test_something(self):

        class Thread(Document):
            posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("Post"))

        class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
            attribute = StringField()

        Thread.drop_collection()

        thread = Thread()
        post = Post()
        post.attribute = "Hello"

        thread.posts.append(post)
        thread.save()

        thread = Thread.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(1, len(thread.posts))
        self.assertEqual("Hello", thread.posts[0].attribute)
```

Comment: thanks! actually the problem was that tastypie "lost" some of the data on the way... so no mongo-problem at all :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be *EmbeddedDocumentField(Post)* (without quotes) instead of *EmbeddedDocumentField("Post")*? I had an exception because of that. (Don't know, perhaps it's an old way of declaring embedded documents)

Answer (score 8):

Embedded documents do not exist as individual, separate instances from their document instance, i.e. to save an embedded document you have to save the document itself where it's embedded into; another way to look at it is that you cannot store an embedded document without an actual document.

This is also the reason that, while you can filter documents that contain a particular embedded document, you will not receive the matching embedded document itself--you'll receive the whole document it's a part of.

```
thread = Thread.objects.first()  # Get the thread
post = Post()
post.attribute = "noodle"
thread.posts.append(post)  # Append the post
thread.save()  # The post is now stored as a part of the thread
```

Comment: But the OP is saying if he emits the `post.save()` an empty post object is saved.

Comment: thanks for the post but i still have the problem with the empty post object